# Adding button dynamically to linear layout with id's?

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout, dynamically-generated

Is there any way to add new buttons dynamically to linear layout with their unique id's. Considering a predefined button to perform this action.

Comment: yes you can add new buttons into LinearLayout

Comment: @M D any refferences or any piece of code

Answer (score 1):

```
LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
    row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
 Button btnTag = new Button(this);
        btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        btnTag.setText("Button 1");
        btnTag.setId(1);
        row.addView(btnTag);
layout.addView(row);
```

Comment: ids shall always be an integer. It cannot be a string

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can dynamically add button to linear layout.

For Eg:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
layout.setId(5000);

Random random = new Random();
//Five button
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
button.setText("Button");
button.setId(random.nextInt(5)); //generate unique number between 0 to 4 and set it as id
layout.addView(button);
}
```

Comment: but in this case all the new buttons created will have same id. Is there any way that id can be generated dynamically

Comment: @user3172071..use Random class to generate a random id..convert it into string form and assign it in setId parameter

Comment: @user3172071..updated code based on your random unique id requirement